# How Tunneling can be configured or set up in this scenario

Tags: tunneling

I have a scenario like there are two servers

1.On the first server where apache and tomcat are running on different ports.For eg ip would be 172.168.2.19

2.There is a second server where jboss and kvsms are running.for eg ip w ould be 172.168.2.20

3.IF a mobile client is trying to hit the first server with url https://172.168.2.19/....../...../....If one resource he is accesing is in first server and the second item has to be fetched from the second server.

how the request can be redirected to the second server without knowing the second servers ip.

how the tunneling can be done from the first server to the second?

Hope you gys understood the question

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to set up a [reverse proxy](https://serverfault.com/questions/8654/what-is-a-reverse-proxy) with Apache that will deal with the client connections to the backends.  There's plenty of documentation here and elsewhere that will tell you how to do this.  You'll need to plan out the URIs that will be proxied to the jboss and kvsms services.

Comment: In Apache.  Look at their documentation, in particular: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse

Comment: my question is reverse proxy has to be configured in the first server or the second one

Comment: It should be configured in the Apache on the first server.

Comment: can you tell me the steps and instructions to configure reverse proxy

Comment: There's documentation all over the Internet.  Just search for "apache reverse proxy example" or something like that, and fit the examples into your actual situation.

Comment: but i guess in this scenario reverse proxy wont work why because for reverse proxy we need to know the ip of the second server to be fetched.but in our scenario the ip of the second server whould not be known to the mobile client sending the request and the request should be redirected to the second server

Comment: Please read up on reverse proxies. The configuration that needs to know the IP of the second server is the first server, which will do the proxy.

Comment: can you just give a clear cut idea to where to start from.i've no idea where to start the process and how

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224664/difference-between-proxy-server-and-reverse-proxy-server