# NOIP Static IP address resetting with router

Tags: ip, router, dyndns

I need a static IP address to access a client's website, which has a list of whitelisted IPs but rejects all others. This is great, except I have a Dynamic IP address and a Talk Talk router.

I registered for a free [NOIP](http://www.noip.com/) account, and created a host. I logged into my router, went to the DynDNS section and then entered my NOIP details, they synced with what was on record and I believed I had a static IP (Is this correct?).

Last week, our internet dropped out and our, apparently static, IP address changed. I logged into NOIP and manually reset it to the previous address. After pressing save NOIP showed the old IP that I wanted to use. Googling What's my IP still showed as the recent, new address so I logged into the router, and re-saved the DynDNS options with the NOIP username and password.

When it finished saving, the router showed the new IP address (not the old one that I was trying to re-use). When I refreshed the NOIP admin screen in my browser, it had also flushed the IP saved in NOIP and replaced it with the new one.

Is there anyway I can get it to re-use the old IP address?
Is NOIP behaving incorrectly or is it behaving exactly as expected?

Comment: Is NOIP a dynamic DNS service or a VPN service?

Comment: I am half inclined to just edit your first sentence out, but I'd rather just explain. Most questions come from someone who did something wrong and can't figure out what. You don't need to preface your question with it, and while it is admirable that you realize it, there can be nothing gained from saying it.

Comment: It offers Free Dynamic DNS – is that the correct service to have a static IP?

Comment: @kasperd It's a competitor to Dyn-DNS.

Comment: @Djave A dynamic DNS service cannot do that. What you are thinking of is called a VPN, that's a different thing. There are other options: A VPS, a proxy with a static IP, or a NAT64 with a static IP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NOIP does not do what you want.

Some ways you might achieve what you want:

1. Purchase a VPN connection with a static IP at the other end
2. Purchase a static IP from your ISP

NOIP and other dynamic DNS services give you a way to dynamically sync your connection to your changing IP.
They in no way actually provide you with a static IP.

> Dynamic DNS (DDNS or DynDNS) is a method of automatically updating a name server in the Domain Name System (DNS), often in Not Real Time, with the active DDOS configuration of its configured hostnames, addresses or other information.

So you did nothing wrong with your NOIP settings, you just picked the wrong service for what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 4):

Best Answer - Call your ISP and get a static IP.

Other Options using a VPS with a static IP:

3. create a [reverse proxy](https://serverfault.com/questions/8654/what-is-a-reverse-proxy) in Apache2 to access their site from the same IP address each time. Also this assumes the application is able to be behind a reverse proxy (trial and error).

This will disable their 'security' of whitelisting IPs by allowing anyone to access their website via the reverse proxy, so you could set your IP address or dynamic-hostname in the allow from field, similar method of what you are trying to do.

- Purchase a VP
- Install APACHE
- Load a standard reverse proxy config (using 10.4.3.2 as VPS IP)

```
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://93.184.216.34/

    <Proxy *>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from dynamicIP.example.org
    </Proxy>

    <Location />
            ProxyPassReverse /
            RequestHeader unset Accept-Encoding
    </Location>
```

And then point DNS for the website (example.com) to your new IP 10.4.3.2
either create the specific zone in local dns

```
www.example.com IN A 10.4.3.2
```

Or Hosts File

```
10.4.3.2 www.example.com
```

4. Forward Proxy, you can do this with socks5 with putty/ssh easily or install a proxy like squid, this will set your source IP to the same, I use firefox's OS independent proxy settings for this purpose, and then chrome for general web access.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. The simplest choice sounds best and I've just gone with the ISP option!