# Forward all incoming traffic without redirect

Tags: nginx, iptables, routing, squid

How to forward all traffic to another domain?  
serverA has a serverA.com domain  
serverB has a serverB.com domain  
I want to forward all incoming traffic from serverA to serverB  
For example, when I open the link below  
serverA.com/example  
This traffic is forwarded to ServerB.com/example  
But I don't want to redirect to serverB

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a Reverse Proxy?](https://serverfault.com/questions/8654/what-is-a-reverse-proxy)

Comment: I'm not sure! Could you send example for this issue?

Comment: Reverse proxy is most likely the thing you are looking. The internet has lots of information on reverse proxies. Please go through them first and then ask specific questions if needed.

Comment: reverse proxy by nginx?

Comment: Nginx works as a reverse proxy yes. So does Apache and IIS.

Comment: Are they on different IP addresses? Are they on different servers?

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are asking for is a "URL redirect".  This guy gets way further into the weeds that I can do in a paragraph here.  ;-)

https://www.semrush.com/blog/redirects/

Then again, I just read your last sentence where you say you do NOT "want to redirect to serverB", so this may or may not be what you're looking for.